# Why is there no leftward-pointing equivalent of unicode "Arrow pointing rightwards then curving upwards"?

Tags: unicode

AFAICT from http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/, there's no left-and-upwards equivalent of unicode `Arrow pointing rightwards then curving upwards` (⤴).

This can of course be simulated by reversing the glyph.  But then `Arrow pointing downwards then curving leftwards` (⤶) and `Arrow pointing downwards then curving rightwards` (⤷) are mirror images of each other, and they both exist.

What's the rationale behind this?

Comment: There are 8 different ways to make such an arrow.  But only 4 Unicode glyphs provided.  In the olden days, the typesetter would simply insert the slug upside down to get the other 4.

Comment: I'm not quite following how "Why are these Unicode characters not defined?" is a programming question.

Comment: This comment strikes me as kind of passive-aggressive and unwelcoming.

Comment: Sorry, the comment above was posted before I'd finished my rant.  It continues:

I'd have appreciated a link to docs saying e.g. that questions that don't explicitly involve code in a Turing-complete language are off-topic.  I think to most of us, "programming" involves much more than writing executable code.  This includes, I would argue, the design of ways to encode human written communications in a format friendly to computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

⤴ and ⤵ were added for compatibility with JIS X 0213:2000:

http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2000/00024.pdf

http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2000/00298-n2258.pdf

http://examples.oreilly.com/cjkvinfo/pdf/jisx0208+0213.pdf (see row 0x82)

The original names for ⤴ and ⤵ (RISING ARROW and FALLING ARROW) explain their suggested use.

⤶ and ⤷ were added for compatibility with STIX font family, often used for mathematical typesetting in TeX. Here is the original proposal: http://www.unicode.org/L2/L1999/99244.pdf

All four curving arrows were added to Unicode 3.2 in 2002. The fact that those two pairs got added at the same time is mostly accidental.

Comment: > The original names for ⤴ and ⤵ (RISING ARROW and FALLING ARROW) explain their suggested use.


That's about as good a rationale as I might hope for.  Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to get the left-up arrow.

Comment: @Chloe https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b11/index.htm might help; it's now U+2B11, "LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH TIP UPWARDS".