# Unicode codepoint for LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER UPWARDS?

Tags: unicode

I found `U+21B5 DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS`: [`↵`](http://graphemica.com/%E2%86%B5)

And I found `U+2934 POINTING RIGHTWARDS THEN CURVING UPWARDS` : [`⤴`](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/)

But where do I find `LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER UPWARDS`, which goes left then up?

This question asks why, but doesn't answer how:

[Why is there no leftward-pointing equivalent of unicode "Arrow pointing rightwards then curving upwards"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437503/)

Answer (score 4):

Use http://shapecatcher.com/

> Leftwards arrow with tip upwards: ⬑
>
> Unicode hexadecimal: 0x2b11 In block: Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows
>   Rate this suggestion: good (undo) | bad More Info
>
> score: 0.831837

Comment: If your browser doesn't show it, like mine, you can see it at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b11/index.htm. The official name is LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH TIP UPWARDS.